# How to fit or zoom out a React Vis.JS Network Graph?

Tags: reactjs, vis.js, react-graph-vis

Good evening,
I have the following setting for my Network Graph:

```
const exceptionsGraph = {
        nodes: graph,
        edges: edges
    }

// Graph Options
const options = {
    height: "80%",
    width: "100%",
    nodes: {
        shape: "dot",
        size: 16
    },
    layout: {
        hierarchical: false
    },
    physics: {
        forceAtlas2Based: {
            gravitationalConstant: -26,
            centralGravity: 0.005,
            springLength: 230,
            springConstant: 0.18,
        },
        maxVelocity: 146,
        solver: "forceAtlas2Based",
        timestep: 0.35,
        stabilization: {
            enabled: true,
            iterations: 2000,
            updateInterval: 25,
        },
    },
    edges: {
        color: "#abb4be"
    }
}
```

And then I call it like this:

```
<Graph graph={exceptionsGraph} options={options} />
```

But when it renders it's all zoomed in, so it looks terrible. Like this:

[image]

And I want it to look like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this on React?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried this way but it didn't work =  <Graph graph={exceptionsGraph} options={options} getNetwork={network => network.fit()}/>

Comment: is this the lib you are using? https://github.com/crubier/react-graph-vis

Comment: Yes @diedu, exactly. That's the library.

Comment: did you try `autoResize` option? https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/index.html

Comment: Yes, I did, but no luck with that :(

Comment: any chance to setup a codesandbox for this?

Comment: Could try, the problem is that I´m cosuming a very huge API for the data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222876/discussion-between-diedu-and-jose-peres).

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the fit function inside of the stabilized event.

Declare events object and define stabilized:

```
const events = {
    stabilized: () => {
            if (network) { // Network will be set using getNetwork event from the Graph component
                network.setOptions({ physics: false }); // Disable physics after stabilization
                network.fit();
            }
        }
    };
```

and this is how you define the Graph component:

```
<Graph
        graph={graph}
        options={options}
        events={events}
        getNetwork={network => {
         setNetwork(network);
        }}
    />
```